# TFS 2010: Real time reporting

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010, tfs-reports, tfs-query, tfs-warehouse

I would like to create a report that shows the iteration status in real time. I was able to create a query on the Tfs_Warehouse database (see below) however I found that this database is populated from the Tfs_Collection database on timely basis.

Is there a way that I can see the changes to the work items reflected in the report right away?

```
 SELECT *
 FROM [CurrentWorkItemView] c 
 left join [vDimWorkItemTreeOverlay] t on t.WorkItemSK = c.WorkItemSK
 where c.IterationName = @iteration and c.System_WorkItemType = 'User Story'
 order by  c.Microsoft_VSTS_Common_StackRank, c.System_id
```

Note: this not the full query because I couldn't fit it nicely. Basically it joins 2 table (CurrentWorkItemView and vDimWorkItemTreeOverlay) to get the user stories and associated tasks to each user story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not through the warehouse. When you need up to date information from the work items, use a work item query in Excel or Visual Studio.

You can also use the TFS api to query the operational datastore directly.